# How to automatically set passphrase of SSH key for running MPI program in a cluster?

Tags: linux, ssh, mpi, ssh-keys, mpich

I am on a **linux cluster with 4 nodes** (n1.a.com, n2.a.com, n3.a.com, n4.a.com) logged in **node 1 (n1.a.com)**.

Now I have an executable named "**sample.out**" which I want to run on the cluster from **node 1**.

I have **SSH keys** set with **passphrase**.

I also have the **host list file** in "**hosts.txt**" as

```
n1.a.com:8
n2.a.com:8
n3.a.com:8
n4.a.com:8
```

So, I am running the following command:

```
mpiexec -n 32 -f hosts.txt ./sample.out
```

However, running this above command, all **the other 3 nodes** are asking for **passphrase simultaneously** as

```
 Enter passphrase for key '/home/a/.ssh/id_dsa': Enter passphrase for key
 '/home/a/.ssh/id_dsa': Enter passphrase for key '/home/a/.ssh/id_dsa':
```

Now **typing the passphrase** here is **not working**! It **repeatedly asks** for the same thing on entering the passphrase.

**My queries**

1. Is there any way to **automatically** pass the passphrase to **all
   the nodes**? (May be through a script)
2. Or, shall I have to use **passphrase-less** keys?
3. Is there any way to **avoid this** by using the "**Torque Batch**" manager which is also installed?

Some may-be useful information of my system:

```
Workload Manager :- Torque Batch System

>>mpich2 --version
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 1.4.1p1
    Release Date:                            Thu Sep  1 13:53:02 CDT 2011
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                      ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:              hwloc plpa
    Resource management kernels available:    user slurm ll lsf sge pbs
    Checkpointing libraries available:
    Demux engines available:                  poll select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid typing in passphrase, a ssh-agent needs to be created and the passphrase be added as follows:

```
ssh-agent $SHELL 
ssh-add
```

Source: [MPICH 1 Documentation: Configuring with ssh](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpich1-old/docs/install/node17.htm)